# How to design multiple columns in ListBox in XAML

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I need to have multiple columns and 2 button and a line at bottom in ListBox such as :

Item1    Item2   item3   Item4       Button1  Button2 
  -----------------------------------------------------

Thanks

------ Update

Have a row to display title for each column

Title1    Title2   Title3  Title4

Item1    Item2   item3    Item4       Button1  Button2 
  -----------------------------------------------------

```
-- Update 


 <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="700,210,0,0" Name="listBox1" Width="650"  Height="532" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
           <Grid Width="650">

             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="80">
             <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
             <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
             <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
             <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


         <StackPanel>


<TextBlock Margin="8,3,0,0" FontSize="22" Foreground="DarkGray" Text="Item code"/>
<TextBlock Margin="8,3,0,0" FontSize="22" Foreground="DarkGray" Text="Description"      TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
<TextBlock Margin="8,3,0,0" FontSize="22" Foreground="DarkGray" Text="Unit Price"/>
<TextBlock Margin="8,3,0,0" FontSize="22" Foreground="DarkGray" Text="Amount"/>

        </StackPanel>



<TextBlock Margin="3,3,10,0" FontSize="22" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="DarkBlue" Text="{Binding No}" Grid.Column="0" />
<TextBlock Margin="8,3,10,0" FontSize="22" Foreground="DarkBlue" Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1" />
<TextBlock Margin="8,3,10,0" FontSize="22" Foreground="DarkBlue" Text="{Binding UnitPrice}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="2" />
<TextBlock Margin="8,3,10,0" FontSize="22" Foreground="DarkBlue" Text="{Binding LineAmount}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="3" />
<Button x:Name="btnTransEdit" Margin="20,3,0,0" Content="Edit" FontSize="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="59" Width="130" Grid.Column="4" />

      </Grid>


    </DataTemplate>

</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Take a look at a DataGrid. Its like a table with multiple columns and rows.

Comment: Do you want selection or just want to show data in tabular manner?

Comment: @Xyroid, just updated as above. A row to describe title for each column. Item1 to Item4 , I will bind them respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quite easily if you use a `LongListSelector` rather than a `ListBox`.

```
<phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ListHeader>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="Item code" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <TextBlock Text="Desc" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <TextBlock Text="Unit Price" Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <TextBlock Text="Amount" Grid.Column="3" />
        </Grid>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ListHeader>

    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding No}" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding UnitPrice}" Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineAmount}" Grid.Column="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" />

                <Button Content="Edit" Grid.Column="4" />
                <Button Content="Delete" Grid.Column="5" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>

    <phone:LongListSelector.ListFooter>
        <Grid Background="white" Height="2" Margin="0,12" />
    </phone:LongListSelector.ListFooter>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```